# Why the quality of image is changed as it is added to a mosaic

Tags: arcmap, imagery, image-mosaic

I have added an image to a mosaic dataset but I have noticed that the quality of the image has been changed automatically.
How to keep the original quality of the image after adding it to the mosaic dataset?
[image]
[image]

Comment: The pixels appear to be the same size, so I don't see any quality issues.  The brightness is different, but that's always going to be an issue when there are multiple images with different statistics in a single renderer.  Have you tried using the mosaic tools to adjust image blending?

Comment: Thanks Vince, what are that tools that can be used  to adjust image blending